# Handlebars + Images in Rails 4 - How do I get the right asset_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, handlebars.js

we are using handlebars inside our rails 4 app.
The issue that bothers us is that we need to make every single hbs file we have in our system that uses images use a .erb extension so when images pre-compile in production we will have the right asset path....

So instead of completely separating the client side code from server code I need to convert this type of code:

sideBarTemplate.hbs:

```
<img src="assets/main/logo.png" alt="image description" width="126" height="34">
```

into this type of code:

sideBarTemplate.hbs.erb:

```
<img src="<%=asset_path('main/logo.png')%>" alt="image description" width="126" height="34">
```

Our goal of-course is to find an alternative to rendering server code into our hbs templates as I don't want our front end devs to write "server side code".

Any solutions exist?

Comment: I actually like this question because I didn't think of mixing the extensions like this with server and front-end code in the first place, and actually suits our needs just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try injecting a helper both in Ruby (`handlebars.register_helper`) and JS (`Handlebars.registerHelper`) that gets a string and prepends the asset root path.

Something like `<img src="{{assetPath 'main/logo.png'}}"`.

On the JS side, get time the asset path from Ruby a single time (e.g. with .js.erb) and use that variable in the helper.

#### Update:

Examples on how to use helpers:

http://jaskokoyn.com/2013/08/08/custom-helpers-handlebars-js-tutorial/
https://github.com/cowboyd/handlebars.rb#block-helpers

#### Caveats

Since `asset_path` outputs a path that can have a digest it makes things a little bit more complex. Just prepending the asset path won't help when you have digest in the URL.

Your options:

- Use https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets that will allow also accessing non-digested URLs
- Or, create a dictionary with all file names as keys and final URL as a value - loop through `Rails.root.join("app/assets/**/*.*")` and for each path your value is `view_context.asset_path(path)` and use this dictionary in the JS helper
- Or, precompile the `.hbs` and replace the asset paths into the final ones (either by using `.hbs.erb` or just with a rake task).

Nothing is perfect but one of the above will get you what you need.

Comment: Have an example to these helper methods? It seems like this is the approach everyone should take but can't find a "best practice" approach out there.

Comment: Shame there is no OOB solution for this and I need to implement on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Put into a .scss file

In your template:

```
<div id='logo'></div>
```

In your .scss file:

```
 #logo{
    background: image-url ('main/logo.png');
    width: 126px;
    height: 34px;
  }
```

Comment: Thats a nice approach, but not always a fit (sometimes you do need img tags that can be manipulated through javascripts)